# How to display a tabularray table in its entirety on specific slides of a Beamer frame?

Tags: beamer, overlays, tabularray

I saved the following LaTeX code in the file `~/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}<1->{Hello}
world
\end{block}

\begin{tblr}{cc}
    \visible<2->{First cell} & \visible<2->{Second cell}
\end{tblr}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The code creates a Beamer presentation consisting of a single frame that encompasses two slides. On the first slide appears a block. On the second slide appear the two cells comprising the single row of a table.

When the following commands are executed in the Terminal:

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
> lualatex Test
```

the compilation completes successfully, with no warnings written to `~/Test.log` (in particular, no warnings to rerun), and the file `~/Test.pdf` is generated. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displays as follows.

[image: A table on the second slide]

The output is as expected, however in order to show the table on the second slide, I used two `\visible` commands: one for each cell of the table's single row.

---

**Question**

Is it possible to display the table starting from the 2nd slide by issuing a single command that would apply to the entire table, instead of issuing a `\visible` command for each cell individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me... Does it help?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{block}<1->{Hello}
            world
        \end{block}
        
        \visible<2->{%
        \begin{tblr}{cc}
            First cell & Second cell
        \end{tblr}}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm normally not a big fan of the `\pause` macro (it is a rather crude command which does not provide a lot of flexibility), but for such a simple case:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}<1->{Hello}
world
\end{block}
\pause
\begin{tblr}{cc}
    First cell & Second cell
\end{tblr}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A minimal working example is, by definition, simple, but it rarely captures the full complexity of the real world code from which the MWE was abstracted. In my real world example your answer fails to work.

Comment: @EvanAad So again an xy-problem :(

Comment: I imagine that in your eyes every question that complies to the Stack Exchange rules of providing a minimal working example is an xy-problem. :(